# How do I use MGO aggregation pipeline to find all embedded documents matching certain criteria

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

Lets say I have the following data in a `Groups` collection in MongoDB

```
[
    {
        “Group”: {
            “_id”: 1,
            “Requests”: [
                {
                    “_id”:1,
                    “name”:”Request A”
                }.
                {
                    “_id”:2,
                    “name”:”Request B”
                }
            ]       
        }
    },
            {
        “Group”: {
            “_id”: 2,
            “Requests”: [
                {
                    “_id”:3,
                    “name”:”Request C”
                }.
                {
                    “_id”:4,
                    “name”:”Request D”
                }
            ]       
        }
    }

]
```

Also, lets say I have the following function

```
func GetRequests(requestIDs []string) (Request[] error){
        //NEED TO IMPLEMENT W/ MGO
}
```

Is there a way to use the aggregation pipeline (or not if its not needed) to return just a projection of the requests matching `requestIDs`?

For example

**Sample input reflecting `requestIds`**

```
[1,2,4]
```

**Sample output from `mgo` aggregation/query**

```
[
  {
    “_id”:1,
    “name”:”Request A”
  },
  {
    “_id”:2,
    “name”:”Request B”
  },
  {
    “_id”:4,
    “name”:”Request D”
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
db.groups.aggregate([{$unwind : '$Requests'},
                     {$match: {'Requests._id' :{$in: [1,2,4]}}}, 
                     {$project : {_id : '$Requests._id',name:'$Requests.name'}}]);
```